# Print a variable to console in Haml to debug Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, console, haml

Just landed on a Rails 3 app that uses haml. I am running Rspec tests and trying to print a value of a variable to console. On erb or in a any .rb file, you simply do:

p my_variable.inspect 
or even string interpolation:

p "this is my variable #{my_variable}"
So when I run my Rspec tests I get a nice printout on the console evaluating my variables. So now, how you do that in Haml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So in Haml just use:

```
- p my_variable
```

Answer (score 15):

it's so annoying to "p" variables as for me, and then search their output. Use better 
https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails and then in view just put

```
- binding.pry
```

and then in console you can debug variables and other stuff :)

Comment: Thank you, I apprecite the tip!